# Can you identify this LEGO car set?

Tags: set-identification

I've got these two pieces, but I do not know which set they came from.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks like part of the Power Racers Theme, [set 8647-1 "Night Racer"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=52182#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D).  From 2005, 76 parts.

[image: set 8647-1 "Night Racer"]